# Modify main function for C++ game file

Tags: c++, .net, dll-injection, game-hacking, proxy

I am trying to modify the main function for a specific decompiled `.exe`. More specifically, I want to remove the reference to GUI from that `.exe` file, so that GUI doesn't get initialised on the startup and also make a call to a different function, which normally gets called from the subsequent GUI dialog.

Example:

```
__int64 __fastcall gladius::Game::main(gladius::Game *this, int a2, char **a3, char **a4)
{
  gladius::Game *v4; // rbx@1

  v4 = this;
  gladius::Game::initialize(this, a2, a3, a4);
  proxy::gui::GUI::run(*((proxy::gui::GUI **)v4 + 5));
  gladius::Game::quit(v4);
  return 0i64;
}
```

called from the entry point to this program:

```
int main(int param_1,char **param_2,char **param_3)

{
  int iVar1;
  Game local_68 [96];
  
  gladius::Game::Game(local_68);
  iVar1 = gladius::Game::main(local_68,param_1,param_2,param_3);
  gladius::Game::~Game(local_68);
  return iVar1;
}
```

I want to change this to something like this:

```
__int64 __fastcall gladius::Game::main(gladius::Game *this, int a2, char **a3, char **a4)
{
  gladius::Game *v4; // rbx@1

  v4 = this;
  gladius::Game::initialize(a2, a3, a4);
  gladius::world::World::create();
  gladius::Game::quit(v4);
  return 0i64;
}
```

Will call to the `gladius::Game::main` be possible from say proxy DLL in this case? Or as it is a main function it won't be called properly?

Comment: This code doesn't look C# to me.

Comment: You are correct. Changed the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with hooking the main function just as it is normally done with hooking technics. Note, that although the function above is called main, it is not the one called when the application starts. So, might be different for the actual main function.